# Passing string value through toastr in codeigniter

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, toastr

Here i want to show validation_error message through tostr so that i made my code like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 toastr.options = {
 "closeButton": true,
 //"allowHtml": true,
 "debug": false,
 "newestOnTop": false,
 "progressBar": false,
 "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
 "preventDuplicates": false,
 "onclick": null,
 "showDuration": "300",
 "hideDuration": "1000",
 "timeOut": "5000",
 "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
 "showEasing": "swing",
 "hideEasing": "linear",
 "showMethod": "fadeIn",
 "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
  }
 </script>


 <?php
 if (!empty($message)) {?>
      <script>  

        toastr.error('<?php echo $message;?>', 'Inconceivable!', {timeOut: 5000})
      </script>
 <?php }?>
```

My $message contains string like this

`'<p>The New Password field does not match the Confirm New Password field.</p>'`

Please, help me to solve.

Comment: what is error your are getting ?

Comment: @MayankVadiya the error means am not able to get toastr view

Comment: Check your browser console any jquery erro

Comment: am getting like this when i console it ReferenceError: $message is not defined but when i did var_dump($message) am getting value

Comment: try with double quote like `toastr.error("<?php echo $message;?>", 'Inconceivable!', {timeOut: 5000})`

Comment: still not getting..

Comment: anybody have any idea

Comment: What does the generated source look like (`toastr.error( $message ...`?

Comment: @ourmandave the generated source looks like `'<p>The New Password field does not match the Confirm New Password field.</p>'`

Comment: I was confused because of the browser console error: `ReferenceError: $message is not defined`. Are you getting any errors in the console?